# Editing an object through a RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http

I am writing a java application where I have some events and I need a client which will be able to add new and cancel existing events. I have written a method which is supposed to connect to the web service and cancel the event through it. But I am having trouble with the connection to the service and I keep getting this `Exception`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 404
at org.unibl.etf.mdp.event.gui.EventAddCancelClient.cancelEvent(EventAddCancelClient.java:131)
at org.unibl.etf.mdp.event.gui.EventController.cancelEvent(EventController.java:39)
at org.unibl.etf.mdp.event.gui.EventForm.buttonCancelActionPerformed(EventForm.java:86)
at org.unibl.etf.mdp.event.gui.EventForm.access$0(EventForm.java:85)
at org.unibl.etf.mdp.event.gui.EventForm$2.actionPerformed(EventForm.java:64)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:269)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6578)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3343)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6343)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2259)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4961)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2317)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4539)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4480)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2303)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2758)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:99)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

This is the code of the method I am using to connect to the service:

```
public static void cancelEvent(int id) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + id); //BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/InfoEvent/service/events/"
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            // os.write("");
            os.flush();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
}
```

Also I am not sure what to do with this portion of code in the method:

```
os.write("");
```

This is the method inside the service which is supposed to cancel the event:

```
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/cancel/{id}")
public static Response setCanceled(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    if(EventSetup.cancelEvent(id)) return Response.status(200).entity(EventSetup.getById(id)).build();
    else return Response.status(500).entity("Error while canceling event!").build();
}
```

Comment: You're getting a 404, that means the resource URL doesn't exist. Look at the comment for the BASE_URL. it shows the base url ending in `/event/`. Then all you do is append the id. Then look at the resource method in the server. `"/cancel/{id}"`. Where does `events` even show up here? Maybe you want to add `cancel` to the URL also, before the id.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thanks, I have overseen that. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting 404 that means the URL doesn't exist.

Try hitting with POSTMAN to this URL using a valid ID

http://localhost:8080/InfoEvent/service/events/ID

You'll see you will get a 404. So basically your endpoint is not correct or the service that should receive that call is not running and up in your computer (because it's localhost).